# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<string>' while using create_token in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to create users entries of Linux users and the required tokens in Django database.

But i get a value error for any user i pass

```
if User.objects.filter(username=user.username).exists():
     token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user.username)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/root/rwi1/apps/rw_rest/rest_api/auth.py", line 47, in create_token
    token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user.username)
  File "/root/rest_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/rest_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 465, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'admin'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to `Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)`. The most likely cause of this error is that Token model defines `user` field as a ForeignKey and so expects a user object or an ID, not a username.